# Connecting to mosquitto server from Intel Edison board

Tags: mqtt, mosquitto, intel-edison

I am trying to connect to Mosquitto server installed locally by running the below script on Intel Edison board -

```
var client = mqtt.connect("ws://localhost:9001");

client.on('connect', () => {  
    console.log("connected");
})
```

But the connect event or the log is never called. Please note that when I try to call this from a webpage using -

```
var client = new Paho.MQTT.Client("localhost", 9001, "clientId");
client.connect(options);
```

This works.

The problem is connecting from the edison board. Did anyone face this issue?

Comment: Any errors in the mosquitto output/log? What do you get if you add a `on('error',function(err){})`  handler to the client? Also is the browser for the webpage actually running on the Edison as well?

Comment: The error function is not getting called too. The brower is on my laptop which is able to connect to mosquitto.

Comment: OK, so broker is running on the laptop not the Edison, in that case the URL should have the IP address of the laptop not localhost (and you need to make sure any firewall on the laptop will allow external connections on port 9001)

Comment: Changing to the IP address worked. However is there not another way instead of providing the IP. The reason is the wifi router may assign a different IP next time my computer starts and I have to change this in the code everytime

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As thrashed out in the comments,

The broker is not running on the Edison, so you can not use `localhost` as the host in the URL. `localhost` is the built in name for the loopback interface so always points to machine the code is running on.

You need to use the IP address of the machine (the laptop) where the broker is running.

If you are running all this in a environment with dynamic IP provisioning then you want to look at something called mDNS/Avahi which allows machines on the same subnet to be addressed by broadcast hostnames in the `.local` domain. That or move the broker to a machine with a static IP address and a DNS entry.